# Unable to make ajax request for Flipkart API

Tags: jquery, ajax, flipkart-api

I am developing an HTML page where I want to get the prices of the products sold on Flipkart.

I have done following code to get items:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
       url: "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/search/json?query=sony+mobiles&resultCount=5",
       type: "GET",
       headers:{"Accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose", "Fk-Affiliate-Id" : "[ID]", "Fk-Affiliate-Token": "[Token]","Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"},
       success: function(){console.log("Success");},
       error: function(){console.log("Fails");}
    });
});
```

But the execution always goes to `error` part. If I run the same query in the REST API tool i.e. Yet another rest client (a chrome tool), I am getting the response. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the error that you get, try with `error: function(jqXHR) { console.log(jqXHR) }` to see the error.

Comment: I ran the same code in another machine and it's working. Will there be any issues with that? The error occurred in Windows 8.1 where the error is not appearing Windows 7.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: The error in console shows: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.`

Comment: I also appended `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"` in header but still not working. @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo

Comment: How did you append in the header?

Comment: I have changed the code in question. I have made 4 headers, previously they were 3.

Comment: I don't see your code running in my `linux` machine too. I think you must check on the server side that the proper permissions are provided for you application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129318/discussion-between-mohemmad-k-and-abhishek-dhanraj-shahdeo).

Comment: Exactly the same issue I am facing, I am able to get response in Postman, but not in chrome console or even jsfiddle. I can't share jsfiddle link as it has token value in it.

Please let me know if you have found any solution? @MohemmadK

Comment: @MohemmadK Did u succeed in fetching the API response? I'm also stuck at same point.